# Что еще нужно знать программисту!

Tags: c

Программирование решил изучать на последнем курсе института. Учился на лингвиста-переводчика. Начал изучение программирования с учебника turbo pascal 7.0, а потом постигал дзен с SICP, и святыми писаниями Таненбаума. Сейчас начал изучать Perl, понравился мне этот язык. К тому же Ларри Уолл сам лингвист, тоже повлияло на выбор. Верстку и javascript изучи базово когда читал SICP. 
Недавно зашел на hascode. И нашел пост в котором было написано: "C вообще классика, его не знать должно быть стыдно", а также "Каждый программист должен мейнстрим языки, а особенно C, иначе он не прогарммист, а кодер". Блин теперь задумался изучать Си или нет? Ведь вроде дельный совет, к тому же большинство поддержало автора. Надо ли еще знать си ребята?

Comment: сколько там того Си, что бы его учить? другое дело идеология указателей - вот это сложно. Но если ее понять, тогда и в других языках будет проще.

Comment: Правильного ответа Вам не даст никто, поскольку мозги у каждого свои, и опыт/знания тоже свои. Если бы Вы знали Си ранее, то perl изучать было бы проще, поскольку все эти awk-perl'ы суть потомки (возможно побочные) Си. А приведённое Вами высказывание... Ну что тут можно сказать? Понты.

Comment: Спасибо, успокоили!

Comment: @alexlz: Это были мои понты :) Всех с Новым Годом!

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! Всех с Новым Годом, еще раз))))!

Comment: @VladD вообще, признать в Вас автора высказывания

       Каждый программист должен мейнстрим языки, а особенно C, иначе он не прогарммист, а кодер

непросто. Ну да ладно. У Си есть ещё один "анти-теоретический" аспект. Язык поощряет массированное использование побочного эффекта, тогда как все или, по крайней мере, большинство теорий этот самый эффект считают весьма паршивой бякой.

Comment: @alexlz: Я автор лишь фразы про то, что "стыдно". Вообще, C и состоит сплошь из побочных эффектов, он на 100% императивен. Поэтому-то и его надо знать. Из теорий выплывают функциональные языки, в которых состояние необходимо эмулировать [вспомогательными средствами](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/State_Monad). Функциональные языки _тоже_ необходимо учить, но они сложнее.

Comment: @VladD А. А мой комментарий про "понты" относится именно к указанной фразе. Решение, принятое в haskell вроде не единственное, знающие люди утверждают, что в Clean метода несколько другая. Но это так. А вот 

     Функциональные языки тоже необходимо учить, но они сложнее.

-- это вопрос сложный. Возможно, проблема не в том, что они сложнее, а в том, что приходится переучиваться. Если нет знаний/опыта императивного программирования, то ситуация может оказаться обратной. Как и в случае "интуитивно понятного интерфейса"

Comment: @alexlz: Я пришёл из императивных языков, и мне кажется, что знать надо и то, и другое. Вообще, знания карман не тянут.

Comment: @VladD Вы уже пришли? Я -- ещё нет. И вообще, первым языком, который я изучал, был язык ассемблера (правда этой архитектуры уже давно в железе нет)

Comment: @alexlz: Я уже пришёл, но не к ФП, а к C# с его garbage collection (стоило мне много нервов), LINQ (~= list comprehension) и async/await (~= goroutines).

К ФП только прихожу покамест.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы несколько буквально воспринимаете эти слова про Си.  Я думаю, что вообще не существует такого языка, который обязательно-преобязательно должен знать каждый программист. Хотя бы в силу того, что у каждого языка есть своя сфера применения. Скажем, вряд ли хорошей идеей будет мысль написать сайт на Си. Следовательно, веб-разработчику этот язык может быть полезен разве что для расширения кругозора. Однако есть ряд языков, из которых стоит знать хотя бы один. Это тот же С, С++, Java, C#, PHP, Python (наверное еще Ruby).  Не то что бы эти языки куда как лучше всех остальных, однако современные реалии таковы, что, скажем, будучи знакомым только с каким-нибудь Haskell (ничуть не менее "крутой", чем вышеперечисленные), вам будет сложнее найти работу.

И вообще, язык - это инструмент, который подбирается к конкретной задаче и может быть заменен другим инструментом, а не волшебная палочка, которая неводомым образом способна решить все проблемы. Си - это тоже инструмент (надо сказать, простой и удобный), подходящий для одних, и бесполезный для других задач.

Answer (score 7):

Смотрите. C -- лёгкий в изучении язык, быстрый, близкий к железу. Он не принесёт вам новых идей (за этим добро пожаловать в SICP), но он даст вам отточенное понимание того, как всё происходит на самом деле без опускания на скучный уровень ассемблера.

Язык C несёт в себе простую идеологию. Это в некотором смысле наиимперативнейший из всех языков, и он показывает, что чисто императивное программирование может и должно быть элегантным. Лаконичность конструкций в стиле K&R несёт кроме чисто программистской и хорошую эстетическую ценность.

Таким образом, лёгкость и ясность языка делают его очень приятным в изучении и использовании. Язык, разумеется, не лишён недостатков, и вы наверняка не захотите писать на нём достаточно абстрактный код. Но в своей области применения язык великолепно справляется.

Несколько побочных плюшек и вкусностей языка C:

- Хотите написать *очень* быстрый код, использующий особенности конкретного железа? Используйте C.
- Хотите понимать программы под Unix? Ну вы поняли.
- Очень многие современные языки происходят от C, умея программировать на нём, вам будет легче понять идеи и конструкции других языков.

Comment: Изучить та изучу, а писать на нем наверное сложно? Ведь постоянно нужно думать о многих тонкостях.

Comment: @Kirles: Да, но это зависит от задачи. Если ваша задача близка к железу, без C не обойтись. Высокоуровневые задачи лучше делать на (неожиданно!) высокоуровневых языках. Я, например, вовсе не пишу на C, но знаю и люблю его.

Answer (score 5):

Я бы не сказал, что знание Си является прям таки обязательным для каждого программиста. Можно проработать всю жизнь с вебом и никогда не сталкиваться с "железом" и низкоуровневыми вещами.

Если вам интересно, то изучайте. Если нет - не стоит себя мучить. Все эти темы "каждый программист должен знать Си" сродни утверждениям вида "каждый должен отслужить в армии" или "не пьешь - значит не русский".

И да, если уж действительно хочется понять, как все устроено там, на низком уровне, то нужен не Си, а Ассемблер. Си скрывает многие вещи, например выравнивание, стек, битовая арифметика, реальное устройство памяти и так далее. Но нужно ли это большинству программистов в работе? Ответ скорее нет, чем да.

p.s. низкоуровневые языки конечно хорошо вправляют мозги, и приучают экономить память и т.д. С другой стороны, как писал кто-то из классиков Perl "в наше время проще докупить планку памяти, чем искать специалиста для оптимизации кода".

Answer (score 4):

C - достаточно простой и популярный язык, позволяющий прочувствовать все тонкости работы с памятью.

Но, ИМХО, если вы ориентируетесь на веб, то пока для вас эти сакральные навыки не являются первоочередными.